# Getting all project "kinds" in a install.ps1 nuget script

Tags: c#, powershell, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I'm trying to code something in an install.ps1 post-install script for a Nuget package that depends on the project type.  If it's a web project type, I want to do something different after install.  So I'm looking at the $project.Kind to determine this.  The problem is that when I test with a WebApi project, this always returns the wrong project kind.  If you look in a newly created C# WebApi project, it has two project types listed in the  element (one for Web Application and one for general C#).  The $project.Kind property is returning the C# identifier...I need to see if it's a web application, so I need the first one as well.  I can't find the proper call to get the list of all project types from $project:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

if($project.Kind -eq {guid goes here}){do my custom thing here...}
```

I've looked through the available accessors on the EnvDte Project object and can't find anything that looks promising.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.aspx

Any ideas?

Comment: Only thing I can see that may be unique are the `<Import>`s. Web projects appear to include `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets`. Could also look for `web.config`.

Comment: Might be some useful information you can use here: http://www.mztools.com/articles/2007/mz2007014.aspx

Comment: Thanks guys, these are both good ideas...will try them out.

Comment: @BradChristie if you want to put this as an answer...glad to give you the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I used was as Brad suggested...just took the low road and looked for a web config like such:

```
$webItem = $null;

try{
    $webItem = $project.ProjectItems.Item("Web.config")
}
catch
{
}

if($webItem -eq $null)
{
  --processing for non-web project.
}
```

Not very elegant, but it appears to work for my simple cases.