# What do the $package and $project params contain in a NuGet install.ps1 script?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package

I'm writing my first install PowerShell script for a NuGet package. I'm trying to copy a file from the `lib` folder into the `tools` folder of another NuGet package. The default install.ps1 script has four parameters, two of which are:

- $package
- $project

They appear to be "objects" of some sort, but I'm not sure what properties and methods they contain. I've done some searching online, but have yet to find a reference or any documentation for these arguments.

Looking at [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28206118/getting-all-project-kinds-in-a-install-ps1-nuget-script), the question contains a link to [Project Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project%28v=vs.120%29.aspx). Is that what `$project` is in the NuGet install.ps1 file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In NuGet 2:

- $project => [EnvDTE.Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.aspx) - which is the Visual Studio object model for a project.
- $package => [NuGet.IPackage](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2/blob/d9e597f7164fd776a0b3162c653afce4cc7c70d3/src/Core/Packages/IPackage.cs) - the NuGet package.

In NuGet 3:

- $project => EnvDTE.Project
- $package => [ScriptPackage](https://github.com/NuGetArchive/NuGet.VisualStudioExtension/blob/f4e0f33079d5e0c3104b5bd186ceb50048bae7c8/src/PackageManagement.VisualStudio/ScriptPackage.cs)

Note that the $package in NuGet 3 has a fewer properties available so some PowerShell scripts included with existing NuGet packages will not work.

You can always see which .NET Type a PowerShell variable is by using `GetType().FullName`, e.g.:

```
Write-Output $project.GetType().FullName
Write-Output $package.GetType().FullName
```